# PHP datetime operations from string format

Tags: php, time

I have several shops in my system. Now i online want to show shops that are open or will open if the nowtime is before the closing time. the time strings I use are 24 hour format like "01:00" and "23:22" I came up with a code like this:

```
    public function willOpen($open, $closed, $nowTime) {
    $open = str_replace(":", "", $open);
    $closed = str_replace(":", "", $closed);
    $nowTime = str_replace(":", "", $nowTime);
    if ($open >= $nowTime) {
        if ($closed <= $nowTime) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But this does not seem right because if the close time is for ex. 01:00 and the current time is 9:00 and the shop will open for ex 11:00 then this code will return false because the close time is smaler then the now time.....

what is the best approach do to this ?

Comment: What do you when a shop open at 8am to 12am, closes for noon and opens again from 3pm to 6pm (15:00-18:00)? I guess you need an multiple open/close-windows. And when these are per day. in you example above, the should woule open at 11am and close at 23:59, open at 0:00 and close at 01:00. Would require a bit of rewrite, but I don't think a simpl open/close could cover it all...(for sure not in germany! ;-)) Also times might be different per weekday!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to go is using DateTime classes, as time operations is supported. So it's would be something like this:

```
function willOpen(Datetime $open, Datetime $closed)
{
    $nowTime = new DateTime(); # defaults to now 

    // if ($nowTime > $closed) ...
}

$open   = Datetime::createFromFormat('H:i', '01:00');
$closed = Datetime::createFromFormat('H:i', '09:00');
```

If closed is the next day so you could a bit like:

```
$closed->add(new DateInterval('P1DT12H')); # 1 day + 12 hours
```

Comment: ah this looks good, im gonnay try something with this approach

Comment: why 1 day and 12 hours... isnt 24 hours not posible ? what is 1 day and 12 hours ?

Comment: @rZaaaa It's just a exemple.

Answer (score 1):

I would cast all of the dates to unix time and compare from that. It's much more accurate and designed for this sort of thing. date("U") is the unix time since epoc (and is an integer), so comparing > and < on it is a breeze.

```
$open = date("U",strtotime($open));
$closed = date("U",strtotime($closed));
$nowTime = date("U");
if ($open >= $nowTime) {
 if ($closed <= $nowTime) {
  return false;
 }
 else {
  return true;
 }
}
return false;
```

Comment: but will it handle the AM times also ? Like in the example i gave

Comment: it will, though you may want to throw a date in there as well. EG: $open = date("U",strtotime(date("Y-m-d") . " " . $open));

Comment: why? I know if a shop is open 9:00 and close is 2:00 the 2:00 will be considered as the next day. Thats why i have not done this. But this way it will not really match because 02:00 is before 09:00 thats the problem if it will compare "times"